# 1 Liner Script to get IP Address of server (ifconfig) and append to HostName to /etc/hosts for matching ipaddress

Tags: linux, sed, awk, hosts

I have the following /etc/hosts file

```
[root@vhost41 tmp]# cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
119.13.248.1 ccvcds1.ihost.com vcds1
171.221.160.11 vhost.ihost.com vhost41


[root@vhost41 tmp]# echo $(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1)
171.221.160.11
```

How can I use sed or awk a single line to add "AWSHOST" to the the matching ip line. So the change would be:

```
[root@vhost41 tmp]# cat hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
119.13.248.1 ccvcds1.ihost.com vcds1
171.221.160.11 vhost.ihost.com vhost41 AWSHOST
```

I tried to pipe the outputof the above command to sed and awk and it is not working. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i "/$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1)[ \t]/ s/$/ AWHOST/ " hosts
```

Comment: Note that this could potentially match lines in your hosts file that you didn't intend, because it's passing the raw ip address -- and all of its dots -- into `sed` as if it were a regular expression. If your `ifconfig` line returns 127.0.0.10, this command will add the hostname to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @RobDavis Good point, I added `[ \t]` at the end to prevent this. Also, the pipe sequence can be extended with `| sed 's/\./\\./g'` to escape the dots.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sed` to to this as such :

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
171.1.1.1 myhost

$ sudo sed -i 's/\(171\.1\.1\.1\).*/&\ mynewhost/g' /etc/hosts

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
171.1.1.1 myhost mynewhost
```

The ampersand `&` will be replaced by the caught expression e.g. here `171.1.1.1 myhost` and then you will append to it an escaped space and new host alias, here `mynewhost`

**EDIT**

As [David Ravetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971315/david-ravetti) stated you can add an  extension to be added to backup files if you do not want the file to be edited in place.

`sed -i .bak ......`

Then the file will be edited in place (replaced with your edit) but the original file will be backed up with `.bak` extension.

Comment: A note for the OP, in case you aren't aware, sed -i means to edit the file in place. If you want to keep a backup of the original hosts file while you're experimenting, you can enter an extension such as sed -i ".bak". Then hosts will contain the processed updates and hosts.bak will contain the original file.

Comment: I edited the sed line to escape the dots. Written `171.1.1.1`, the string would also match "171.121.115.42". By escaping the dots as `171\.1\.1\.1` it will only match literal dots.

Comment: I will not know the ip address of the server and that is returned using the command: echo $(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1) | sed or awk. The problem is when I use sed I cannot get the output of the echo from the previous command. The main problem is that it needs to be a 1 liner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`sed -i  "s/\(171.221.160.11\) \(.*\)/\1 \2 MYHOST/g" temp.txt`

and this is with `awk`

```
awk '{if ($1 == "171.221.160.11") {b=$1;for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i){$1="";a=a" "$i;}$0 =b" "a" ""MYHOST3" } print}' temp.txt > temp2.txt
```

I wasn't able to decide what to choose `sed` or `awk` , so now i always do in both :)